# EJB avoid very long transaction (Wildfly)

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have the following service which is basically scheduled at certain time intervals to do the following:

- get a list of urls to download from
- perform the downloads
- save them to disk
- persist the entities resulting from the downloads with their location on the disk

These downloads may all take lets say 1-2 hours. From what you will see in my class layout and from what I understand I am permanently in a Transaction for the entire duration of the scheduled service.

```
@Stateless
public class TimedService {

    @EJB
    private Facade facade;

    @Schedule(hour="*/12")
    public void run() {

        List<String> urls = getAllUrls();

        urls.forEach(u -> {
            facade.downloadFromUrl(u);
        });

    }
}

@Stateless
public class Facade {

    @EJB
    private Dao dao;

    public void downloadFromUrl(String url) {

        //this is the download part that may take a couple of minutes
        byte[] bytes = NetUtils.getByteArrayFromUrl(url);

        //if download was succesfull
        if(bytes != null) {
            //save the filename to disk
            String fileName = createFileName(url);
            Files.write(fileName, bytes);

            //save entity to the database with the fileName location
            Entity e = new Entity(fileName);
            dao.merge(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically either Wildfly times out the transaction (which default is 5 minutes) or I change it to be something huge like timeout in 24 hours.

If I understand correctly even though the timeout in `Facade#downloadFromUrl` transaction may not be triggered since a single download doesnt last that long, I am still in the `TimedService#run` transaction which will be **open for the entire duration** that it takes all downloads to complete.

So is there a better approach than just adjusting transaction timeout to a huge number?

Comment: Well, simply make the run() method not transactional.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not very familiar with the TransactionAttribute notations.

Comment: That's why documentation exists: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html

Answer (score 2):

You should consider multi - threading the downloads using an ExecutorService or container managed thread pool if your server provides it.  This will improve overall throughput.   Also in general it is a good idea to put the transaction at service level to guarantee operation is atomic but in this case it's a background task so transaction can be placed when data is written to db.  If set of downloads needs to be atomic you can join on the results from the executor submission of all downloads to create barrier where all db writes occur after all downloads completed.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be using **JMS**. If you are happy with 1 transaction per 1 download instead of a single transaction for the whole process, you can have `run()` sending a message to a **Message Driven Bean** for each URL to download an in the MDB do `facade.downloadFromUrl(u);`